# Splitting subheadings in one column into multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to do some classification and regression analysis on a system log that I received from a client.  The log (a csv file), contains the log for 12h in one single column with break containing the start of the next measurement. 
Example:

```
Time                Average CPU Utilization
2018/05/11 02:35    0.9006184
2018/05/11 02:40    0.7937351
.
.
.
Time    Frames In /sec
2018/05/11 02:37    32359.08251
2018/05/11 02:40    31141.59141
.
.
.
```

There is about 19000 lines of this with around 30-40 sub headings.  What would be a quick way to separate each break of the log into separate column headings instead of me copy and pasting them manually next to each other.

Is it possible in R?  Or is there other suggestions?

Comment: What are those `.` shown ?

Comment: There are another 50 or so iteration per heading and then the next heading.

Comment: okay, but do you have any pattern  that is repeated for the heading.  In the example, the common element is "Time".  Also, is there words that is not the header

Comment: Time is present in every instance, and there is only two headings.  There is additional information but the headings are unique. I would like to do a CART analysis in order to identify possible inputs to a root cause for an IT incident that occurred at 13:01 and 13:33.

Comment: Why would this *not* be possible? Have you even tried reading the file line by line? This seems to be basic R programming you reading lines from a file.

Answer (score 0):

We could read the data with `readLines`, then create a grouping variable using `grep` and `cumsum`, `split` the data into a `list` of data and read with `read.table`

```
i1 <- grepl("Time", lines)
lapply(split(lines, cumsum(i1)), function(x) read.table(text = x[-1], header = FALSE))
```

#### data

```
lines <- readLines("file.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks.  Will give it a try.

Comment: Ok, I might need some coaching on this R thing. Ive installed R and R Studio on my Mac.  I was able to import the txt and Excel file into R studio, but when I run the script above, I get error messages

Comment: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 144 did not have 3 elements

So, I have progressed a little bit, although I am stuck with the first break in the data.  Line 144 is the next instance of the KPI.  There is only two elements (time and the KPI, although I can see how it would state 3 elements as the time column has date and time together.  Is this not allowed?

Comment: @KuantumPhoenix  Probably, you need `fill = TRUE` i.e. `read.table(text = x[-1], header = FALSE, fill = TRUE)`